# Project Euler's Fibonacci - Why does this answer work?

Tags: python

The following solution is still not quite fitting in my head. Why is it `f1 = f2` and `f2 = add` in the `while` loop?

```
n = 4000000

f1 = 1
f2 = 1
add = 0
result = 0

while add < n:
   f1 = f2
   f2 = add   
   add = (f1 + f2)         
   if add % 2 == 0:
       result = result + add

print (result)
```

I've been tackling some of the Project Euler's questions just for some creative exercise outside of my free online course (a friend told me the best way to learn is to tackle projects).

I tried it on my own, tried a recursion, realized that it was way too slow, and came onto Stack Overflow to see what's up. Subsequently, I've seen some really cool answers for Question #2 in Project Euler, which asks:

> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

My goal is to understand and learn, and I've begun to understand the difference between recursion and iteration.

Comment: Those two lines are what continue the fibonacci sequence. Each element of the sequence is the sum of the previous 2 (`add`). By reassigning `f1` and `f2` in the loop, you are moving up the sequence.

Comment: To calculate the next value in the sequence, you need the preceding two values. The assignments merely shift along the sequence; you start with the first 2, next iteration you have values 2 and 3, then you have 3 and 4, etc.

Comment: I see. I just tried manually writing it out as well, and it makes much more sense. Thank you both! And thank you Martijn Pieters for editing my question -- definitely makes it more straightforward. Will keep those tips in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each value in the Fibonacci sequence is the sum of the preceding two values. `f1` and `f2` merely track those previous two values.

By assigning the value of `f2` to `f1` and the previous result `add` to `f2`, the algorithm shifts along the sequence to only keep the last two calculations.

In steps:

1. `f1 = 1`, `f2 = 0`, result `add = 1`
2. `f1 = 0`, `f2 = 1`, result `add = 1`
3. `f1 = 1`, `f2 = 1`, result `add = 2`
4. `f1 = 1`, `f2 = 2`, result `add = 3`
5. `f1 = 2`, `f2 = 3`, result `add = 5`
6. `f1 = 3`, `f2 = 5`, result `add = 8`

etc., with the value from `add` shifting to `f2` and the value that was in `f2` shifting to `f1` each step.

Answer (score 2):

You can draw a timeline like this on paper to aid in understanding algorithms:

[image]

It shows how the variables (rows) get transformed in the various iterations (columns)

Sorry for the pen & paper quality ;-)

Comment: This is helpful!! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You said you've worked with the recursive case, but just to make sure we're on the same page, consider the generic case of the function returning the numth number in the sequence (0th is 0, 3rd is 2, 7th is 13, etc):

```
def rfib(num):
    return num if num <= 1 else rfib(num - 1) + rfib(num - 2)
```

Now, the generic iterative version:

```
def ifib(num):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    for _ in range(num):
        a, b = b, a + b
    return a
```

I think the example you posted might have confused you where it split the b = a + b step into two steps.  But it's really just doing the same thing as the recursive version, which is adding the previous two numbers in the sequence.

Comment: I see! Hm. So in the recursive case, this rfib(num - 1) and rfib(num - 2) is being done again and again even for rfib(1), for instance. Whereas in the iterative case, it is "storing" the sums so that it doesn't have to re-calculate. So like you said, they do the same thing, just in a slightly different manner/speed. Would this be a correct explanation of the differences?

Comment: Not for rfib(1) actually, since that's one of the exit conditions for the recursive function (the 0th and 1st numbers in the sequence are 0 and 1).  But yeah, for rfib(2), it calls rfib(0) and rfib(1).  You're right that the two functions do the same thing, and I think you can see why the iterative version is much much better for larger numbers (the recursive version calls itself a LOT for larger numbers).  As a general statement in Python, the recursive version of a function will be easier to understand, while the iterative version will be faster.